# Mongoose not creating document for a new collection

Tags: express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new document for a collection when I execute a Submit button in a form in my MEAN stack application (using Angular 7, Express 4, Mongoose 4.4.5.)  It just turns out that this collection doesn't yet exist in my mongodb database.  I've gone through several of the responses on stackoverflow regarding similar issues and modified my code accordingly, yet no luck.  mongod doesn't even log any activity when I click a submit button that should result in creation of a new document, even though I already have an open connection to mongodb.  Here's the code:

Express app.js code:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var contactUsRouter = require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes', 'contactUs'));
var app = express();

//Connecting to MongoDB
var mongoose_uri = process.env.MONGOOSE_URI || "mongodb://ratingsville:15Rville1904@localhost:27017/databank?authSource=admin";
mongoose.set('debug', true);
mongoose.connect(mongoose_uri);
//MongoDB successful connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', ()=>{
  console.log('MongoDB connected at port 27017');
});
//MongoDB connection error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})

app.use('/api/contactus', contactUsRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

contact_us_message.js (defines new schema and model):

```
"use strict";

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var contactUsMessageSchema = new Schema({
  subject: {type: String},
  message: {type: String, required: true},
  senderEmail: {type: String, required: true},
  dateSent:{type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var contactUsMessage = mongoose.model('contactUsMessage', contactUsMessageSchema);
module.exports = contactUsMessage;
```

contactUs.js (router):

```
"use strict";

var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var contactUsMessage = require('../models/contact_us_message');


router.route('/')
    .get(function(req,res,next){
      res.send(req)
    })
    .post(function(req,res,next){
      console.log("Req body: ", req.body);
      contactUsMessage.create({
        subject: req.subject,
        message: req.message,
        senderEmail: req.senderEmail
      }, function(err){
        if (err) {return (err)}
        else {console.log('Successful')};
      });
      res.send({result: 'hello'});
    });


module.exports = router;
```

When I execute the submit button which results in a request.post call in the angular app, I would expect the express router to execute the call and create a new document in collection contactUsMessage as well as create a new collection named contactUsmessage (if one doesn't already exist).  Neither of that happens.  What's wrong with the "contactUsMessage.create" command in the router file (contactUs.js)?  Also, why does my mongod log (shown below) keep on adding another connection every few seconds?  Is that a good thing?  If not, how to limit it?

ng log shows: `[HPM] POST /api/contactus -> http://localhost:8085`

mongod log shows:

```
2019-05-12T17:43:05.774-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:53801 #14 (14 connections now open)
2019-05-12T17:43:05.777-0400 I NETWORK  [conn14] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:53801 conn14: { application: { name: "MongoDB Shell" }, driver: { name: "MongoDB Internal Client", version: "3.4.3-10-g865d2fb" }, os: { type: "Windows", name: "Microsoft Windows 8", architecture: "x86_64", version: "6.2 (build 9200)" } }
2019-05-12T17:43:05.822-0400 I ACCESS   [conn14] Successfully authenticated as principal ratingsville on admin
```

npm log shows: `POST /api/contactus 200 8.930 ms - 18`

Answer (score 0):

The issue behind my question lies with the use of "req" in the mongoose create command.  It should have been "req.body.[parameter]" instead of "req.[parameter]", which itself has an undefined value because the parameters are within "req.body", not directly within "req".  Code for contactUs.js has been modified as shown below and works well.

```
router.route('/')
    .get(function(req,res,next){
      res.send(req)
    })
    .post(function(req,res,next){
      console.log("Req body: ", req.body);
      contactUsMessage.create({
        subject: req.body.subject,
        message: req.body.message,
        senderEmail: req.body.senderEmail
      }, function(err){
        if (err) {return (err)}
        else {console.log('Successful')};
      });
      res.send({result: 'hello'});
    });
```

Alternatively, we can use the following:

```
contactUsMessage.create(req.body,
    function(err){
        if (err) {return (err)}
        else {console.log('Successful')};
      });
```

where "req.body" replaces:

```
{subject: req.body.subject,
message: req.body.message,
senderEmail: req.body.message}
```